# .htaccess condition - action dependent on filetype

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

What I have is a rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !abc.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some.php [L]
```

what's necessary to add condition where .html filetype will also run under that rule?

Answer (score 1):

It's late so I may be wrong, but this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !abc\.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*\.html)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some.php [L]
```