# .htaccees condition - run, if filetype is defined

Tags: .htaccess

There's similar question: [.htaccess condition - action dependent on filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573331/htaccess-condition-action-dependent-on-filetype) however no correct answer was posted...

How to "detect" file type with .htaccess's mod_rewrite condition?

Comment: I think the question you refer to has correct answer but not marked. Do you want to apply a rewrite condition according to file type or do you want to do something else, for instance limit access to the file?

Comment: Yes, I do believe the answer there is correct, if the condition is not `abc.php` **and** any file ending in `.html`. It does not account for subdirectories, etc., but the original question didn't make that a condition of the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter files by extension.
This can be done by defining a single Rewrite Condition like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(htm|html)$
```

just above your:

```
RewriteRule ...
```